# Custom Post Type Limited to Single Post

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Being new to WP, I have read up how to create custom post types etc but I have not come across how to achieve this: I need to create a custom post type whereby only one entry is allowed per logged-in user. Thereafter there will only be an option for the user to modify the existing record. I know this sounds counter-intuitive to the definition of a post but that's the requirement.

I need help with the code to place this limit (and where exactly it should be placed) or guidance if there is a more appropriate structure for what I'm trying to achieve.

The ultimate use is for front-end posting by registered users who have authenticated (non-admin users are redirected after log in to the page where this post can be entered; back-end disabled for all except admin.)

Comment: you want to provide in administrator side or front end side?

Comment: I added the last paragraph to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow these steps,

1> create a custom post type.

- [How to Create Custom Post Types in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-post-types-in-wordpress/)

2> Create a form in front-end to get inputs from your to create a post

- [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

3> add a condition on your form

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
  if(get_the_author_posts()>1){
    //hide form give form link to edit post
  }
  else{
    //display form
  }
}else{
  echo "You must log in!";
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

For more information,

- [Posting via the Front End: Editing and Deleting](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/posting-via-the-front-end-editing-and-deleting--wp-27172)

Comment: Author might have posts of other types therefore should this not read: if(get_the_author_posts()=1) ? Also I need to Test for that particular custom post type so is there a way to if(get_the_author_posts($custom_post_type_id)=1) or something like that?

Comment: check this function count_user_posts( get_current_user_id() , $post_type ); -
 [explnation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/count_user_posts) for count user posts by post type and user id